# Show warning message when sending email

Tags: node.js, api, outlook-addin, office-js

I would like to display a warning message when sending a email. And only send after the user click on dismiss. 
I set the persistent to true on notificationMessages. 
But when sending the email, the message will be quickly shown but the email will be sent straight away without me having a chance to read the message.

Any idea what could I do?

```js
 Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.addAsync("cost_warning", { 
  type: "informationalMessage", 
  message: "message",
  icon : "iconid",
  persistent: true
 });
 event.completed({ allowEvent: true });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [NotificationMessage.getAllAsync API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.notificationmessages?view=office-js#getallasync-options--callback-).

Just set up an interval using [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) and wait till notificationMessage.getAllAsync() stops returning your notification, then call 
`event.completed({ allowEvent: true });`

But 
I would recommend you to use a [dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.ui?view=office-js#displaydialogasync-startaddress--options--callback-) and display a webpage with the necessary information instead of using a notification message.

Notification messages are not meant for blocking information, dialog is more appropriate in this scenario.

Edit:

```
// Add your notification message
var interval = window.setInterval(checkNotificationMessages, 2000);
function checkNotificationMessages() {
    Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.getAllAsync(
        function (asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.status != "failed") {
                if (asyncResult.value.length == 0 ) {
                    window.clearInterval(interval);
                    // Perform some action and decide whether to allow/block send
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. the dialog API seems to allow to display another webpage. But all I want is to display a confirmation dialog. 
For the setInternal approach, do you have some sample code?

Comment: @KevinRen I have updated my answer with an example of setInterval, but still I recommend you to use dialogs because notification message is not effective for UI blocking scenarios.